# Using for loop from range value

Tags: c, pic

I got some data from this table:
[image]

Can it be use using (for loop) ?

Recently, I used (if else) function, but it seem too longer.

I am new to C programming. Here the code (if else) function that I done :

```
        if (0 < result < 409  ) // 0 to 408
        {
            volt = 0 ;
        }
        else if (409 < result < 818 ) //408 to 817
        {
            volt = 1 ;
        }
        else if (818 < result < 1227 ) //818 to 1226
        {
            volt = 2 ;
        }
        else if (1227 < result < 1636 ) //1227 to 1635
        {
            volt = 3 ;
        }
        else if (1636 < result < 2045 ) // 1636 to 2044
        {
            volt = 4 ;
        }
        else if (2045 < result < 2454 ) // 2045 to 2453
        {
            volt = 5 ;
        }
        else if (2454 < result < 2863 ) //2454 to 2862
        {
            volt = 6 ;
        }
        else if (3271 < result < 2863 ) //2863 to 3271
        {
            volt = 7 ;
        }
        else if (3860 < result < 3272 ) //3272 to 3860
        {
            volt = 8 ;
        }
        else if (4094 < result < 3861 ) //3861 to 4094
        {
            volt = 9 ;
        }

        else if (result >= 4095 ) //4095++
        {
            volt = 10 ;
        }
```

Comment: How about reading a good C book? That will show you all the nice things you need to solve this on your own.

Comment: It is good to fix your compilation errors before posting here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, `409 < result < 818` is not an expression that does what you think it does in C. It may make sense mathematically but C needs you to be slightly more specific:

```
(409 < result) && (result < 818)
```

---

> Explaining further, the expression `409 < result < 818` will first work out the truth value for `409 < result`, giving either zero or one, which we'll call `X`. Then the result of *that* will be fed into `X < 818` to give a new truth value.
>
> So, in that case, you'll always get true simply because an `X` of zero or one is *always* less than `818`. The following program shows this in action:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Between400And600 (int n) {
    printf ("%d between 400 and 600? Old = %d, new = %d\n",
        n,
        400 < n < 600,
        (400 < n) && (n < 600));
}

int main (void) {
    Between400And600 (111);
    Between400And600 (555);
    Between400And600 (999);
    return 0;
}
```

> The first result on each line is your original one, `old`. The second is my suggested fix, `new`. As you can see, all of your expressions give `1` (true) while the fix only gives true for the value between the limits:

```
111 between 400 and 600? Old = 1, new = 0
555 between 400 and 600? Old = 1, new = 1
999 between 400 and 600? Old = 1, new = 0
```

---

On top of that, some of your range checks are off, with the numbers being in the incorrect order. Other than the possibility of some high-order math I'm not aware of, no number can be greater than `3860` and less than `3272` at the same time:

```
else if (3860 < result < 3272 ) //3272 to 3860
```

And, on top of that, the exclusive use of `<` rather than `<=` means that you're *missing* some cases, such as when `result` is `409`.

If you're just after a succinct way to do the mapping, I'd opt for something like:

```
unsigned int getVolt (unsigned int adc) {
    if (adc <  409) return 0;
    if (adc <  818) return 1;
    if (adc < 1227) return 2;
    if (adc < 1636) return 3;
    if (adc < 2045) return 4;
    if (adc < 2454) return 5;
    if (adc < 2863) return 6;
    if (adc < 3272) return 7;
    if (adc < 3681) return 8;
    if (adc < 4095) return 9;
    return 10;
}
```

and just call it with:

```
volt = getVolt (result);
```

That's a lot shorter, a lot clearer, and therefore a lot less prone to error.

Given that all but the last is a multiple of `409`, you could shorten it even more, to something like:

```
unsigned int getVolt (unsigned int adc) {
    if (adc < 4090) return adc / 409;
    if (adc < 4095) return 9;
    return 10;
}
```

but you're losing the clarity (and flexibility, should the thresholds change) in that case so I'd probably stick with my first implementation, given it's not *too* big. Of course, if it ended up being fifty `if` statements, I'd probably look for a better solution, but ten lines of code isn't too bad.

---

If you wanted to keep the code relatively short yet still allow for a much larger number of checks, you could make it table driven with something similar to:

```
unsigned int getVolt (unsigned int adc) {
    const static unsigned thresholds[] = {
         409,  818, 1227, 1636, 2045, 2454, 2863, 3272, 3681, 4095,
         // as many entries as you need.
    };
    const static int sz = sizeof(thresholds) / sizeof(*thresholds);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < sz; idx++)
        if (adc < thresholds[idx])
            return idx;

    return sz;
}
```

That has the limitation that the return values have to be consecutive starting at zero (the same as the index, `0..9` plus the default of `10`) but that's okay for your particular case.

Comment: can I know, the `0 < result < 409`? It means `result` is more than or less than zero. Next, `result` is less than or more than `409` ?

Comment: @NazifJaafar: Few programming languages support a trinary comparison. C is none of them. You have to split this into two sepearte comparisons. Please read a book or a tutorial. No offence, but you are lacking elemental  knowledge, so please learn to walk before starting to run.

Comment: @NazifJaafar, added some more explanation to the answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo good spot with the divisible by 409, you really know your 409 times table ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ditto on the first part of what paxdiablo said, but to answer your question, you *could* put this into a for loop, but if you look at your numbers, the range of numbers in each `if`/`else if` block of code is the same; 409. Then inside that block, you're setting volt = the number of the section you're in. In the first section you're setting volt = 0, in the second it's volt = 1, and so on. Since the range in each section goes up by 409 each time, you can just replace everything you have written with
`volt = result / 409`.

Remember that (assuming result is an integer) the c language will process `result/409` using integer division. So if result is >= 0 and < 409, result/409 with equal 0. If result is >= 409 and < 818, then result/409 will equal 1, and so on. This does, however, mean that if result = 4094, volt will equal 9, which isn't what your chart says should happen but might be what you want.

If you need to do something similar (with constantly increasing ranges), then you would probably would want to use a for loop. A for loop should also be faster (I think). You'd have to make use again of the fact that your ranges go up by constant increments of 409, and so do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++ )
{
    int lowerBound = (result / i);
    int upperBound = (result / i + 408);
    //or something
    //...other necessary code here...
}
```

Comment: Good call, though I think it should be `409` rather than `408`. The last value of `4095` appears also to be a special case since the "multiple of 409" threshold would be `4090`.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a 12-bit (4096-count) ADC, with a full-scale input of 10V. It is linear across that scale, so no table or loop is necessary:

```
#define ADC_BITS       12
#define ADC_MIN_VOLTS  0
#define ADC_MAX_VOLTS  10

#define ADC_COUNTS     (1 << ADC_BITS)
#define ADC_VRANGE     (ADC_MAX_VOLTS - ADC_MIN_VOLTS)


double adc_counts_to_volts(int counts)
{
    return counts * (double)ADC_VRANGE / ADC_COUNTS;
}
```

You can replace this with an integer version to give an integer output:

```
int adc_counts_to_volts(int counts)
{
    return counts * ADC_VRANGE / ADC_COUNTS;
}
```

Comment: Watch out at the top end of that range, it's not *quite* linear there.

Comment: @paxdiablo Hmm, good call - I only sampled a couple points. Perhaps the datasheet has more information about the non-linearity of this device.